# Django - automatically save a copy of an object ID to a second table

Tags: python, django, signals

I want my Django application to also save the ID of a newly created Post object to my Post_Collection table as soon a actual Post object gets created therefor I tryd the following solution which sadly does nothing so far:

models.py

```
collectable_post_models = models.Q(app_label='App', model='post_model1') | models.Q(app_label='App', model='post_model2') | models.Q(app_label='App', model='post_model3')

class Post_Collection(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=collectable_post_models,
                                     related_name='collections', related_query_name='collection',
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=False)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('content_type', 'object_id')
        verbose_name = "Post Collection - HELPER TABLE"
        verbose_name_plural = "Post Collections - HELPER TABLE"
        ordering = ['-date_added']

    # currently not working
    @receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
    def ensure_post_exists(sender, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('published_date', False):
            Post_Collection.objects.get_or_create(post=kwargs.get('instance'))
```

I would expect that each time I create a new Post element the ID gets saved to the Post_Collection table also.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a *post* field in *Post_Collection* (it doesn’t appear in the model definition but you assign it in the last line), you may do something like:

```
class Post(models.Model):
     # fields

     def save(*args, **kwargs):
         is_new = not self.pk

         super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

         if is_new:
             Post_Collection.objects.get_or_create(post=self)
```

Comment: First of all thx for your answere. I replaced post=self with object_id=self as this is the field that holds the ID for the Post model I want to reference. Sadly you code does not seem to have any effect. I first tought that im talking to the Post model if I use post=kwargs.get('instance') but from what I understand now my implementation seems to be wrong

Comment: @MarkusBrede Sorry if I was not clear, with my code, now you should remove the ensure_post_exists method, if it doesn’t work yet, then, is it showing any kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue like so:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
...
  if not Post_Collection.objects.filter(object_id=self.pk).exists():                     
     Post_Collection.objects.create(content_object=self)

def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
...
  Post_Collection.objects.filter(object_id=self.pk).delete()
```

I simply added this to the model I wanted to send over to the collection index.
If a Post now gets created or deleted it will either and also get added or dropped from the Post_Collection index.